# Convert 6.3GB .TIFF to GeoJSON with gdal_polygonize.py Crashes at 70%

Tags: geojson, tiff, gdal

hoping for a bit of help with this question as I've been trying to figure out how to convert a 6.33GB .TIFF file to GeoJson format for a couple of weeks now.

I'm trying convert this data set - http://cidportal.jrc.ec.europa.eu/ftp/jrc-opendata/GHSL/GHS_POP_GLOBE_R2022A/GHS_POP_E2020_GLOBE_R2022A_54009_100/V1-0/ (a data set of the world's population) to GeoJSON format so it can be uploaded to a Mapbox tileset using Mapbox Tiling Service.

I am using the following command in GDAL:

```
gdal_polygonize.py ghs.tif -f "GeoJSON" myPolygonizedImage.geojson
```

Output:

```
Creating output myPolygonizedImage.geojson of format GeoJSON.
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70..zsh: killed     gdal_polygonize.py ghs.tif -f "GeoJSON" myPolygonizedImage.geojson
```

It runs for ~3-5 hours and creates an output file of about 110GB before it crashes shortly after 70%. I've tried running it multiple times and it always crashes at the same point. My first thought was memory and it certainly uses a lot but it always seems to keep ~2GB of memory free.

I'm not married to gdal to convert it but that seems to be the best option for a file of this size. Any advice would be greatly appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: Do you have enough space on your hard drive?

Comment: Why would you want to polygonize floating point data to begin with? You could also more or less convert every pixel to a polygon (ignoring 0 perhaps).

Comment: @adiaan Yes plenty of space left on my hard drive!

Comment: @rutgerkassies Mapbox only accepts GeoJSON format for their Mapbox Tiling Service.

Comment: Sure, but polygonize connects same-valued pixels, which basically don't exist in your data. If you let go of that requirement, you can easily chunk the job into small pieces.